# Timezone and Daylight Savings Issues

Tags: php, date, timezone, dst

I've looked through the other solutions on SO and none of them seem to address the timezone/dst issue in the following regard.

I am making calls to [NOAA Tide Prediction API](http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/axis/) and [NOAA National Weather Service API](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/rest.php) which require a time range to be passed for retrieving data. For each location in my database, I have the timezone as a UTC offset and whether daylight savings time is observed (either 1 or 0). I'm trying to format some dates (todays and tomorrow) to be what the LST (Local Standard Time) would be in it's own timezone so I can pass to these API's.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to know if a date, such as todays, is within the daylight savings time range or not.

Here is what I have so far:

```
// Get name of timezone for tide station
// NOTE: $locationdata->timezone is something like "-5"
$tz_name = timezone_name_from_abbr("", $locationdata->timezone * 3600, false);
$dtz = new DateTimeZone($tz_name);    

// Create time range
$start_time = new DateTime('', $dtz);
$end_time = new DateTime('', $dtz);
$end_time = $end_time->modify('+1 day');

// Modify time to match local timezone
$start_time->setTimezone($dtz);
$end_time->setTimezone($dtz);

// Adjust for daylight savings time
if( $locationdata->dst == '1' )
{
   // DST is observed in this area. 

   // ** HOW DO I KNOW IF TODAY IS CURRENTLY DST OR NOT? **  

}           

// Make call to API using modified time range
...
```

How can I go about doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP's time and date functions:

```
$tzObj = timezone_open($tz_name);
$dateObj = date_create("07.03.2012 10:10:10", $tzObj);

$dst_active = date_format($dateObj, "I");
```

If DST is active on the given date, `$dst_active` is `1`, else `0`.

Instead of specifying a time in the call to `date_create` you can also pass `"now"` to receive the value for the current date and time.

However, like Jon mentioned, different countries within the same timezone offset may observe DST while others may not.

Comment: However, beware these issues. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40743
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49914
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51051
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51557
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52480
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54340
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54655
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55253
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60873
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60960
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61022
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61311
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61530
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61955

Answer (score 2):

> For each location in my database, I have the timezone as a UTC offset and whether daylight savings time is observed (either 1 or 0).

That's not enough information. There can be multiple time zones which all have the same standard offset, all observe DST, but perform DST transitions at different times. (Indeed, historically they may also start and stop observing daylight saving time for several years.)

Basically, your database *should* contain a time zone ID, not the offset/DST-true-or-false. (Assuming PHP uses the zoneinfo time zone database, a time zone ID is something like "Europe/London".)

EDIT: To find the offset of a given `DateTime`, you can call [`getOffset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.getoffset.php), which you can then compare with the standard time offset. But unless you have the *definitive* time zone ID, you *will* be risking getting the wrong zone.

Comment: The function `timezone_name_from_abbr("", $locationdata->timezone * 3600, false);` returns the time zone ID from an offset, so `-5` would probably return 'America/New York`.

Comment: @cillosis: Are you relying on that mapping being accurate? Because it *will* be ambiguous. Will edit to answer the specific question though...

Comment: I'm sure there will be ambiguity, but at the moment I'm not concerned about that. I'm more concerned with identifying if an area is currently observing DST or not.

Comment: @cillosis: Well it's hard to know that if you don't know what area you're actually interested in... but as I said, you can call `getOffset` on the DateTime to find out.

Comment: You can keep your tzdata (and thus DST) definitions up to date with a cron job to update this PECL package often: http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb

Answer (score 0):

Cillosis,
I hope you are not working with Java! I am and fought with time all the time. I also work with weather data. Most of the data I use is in local standard time (ignoring daylight saving time). I also need to use times from other time zones and found that Java kept reading my computer's time zone. I also kept running into deprecated classes. I came up with a solution that works. It is a bit of a kluge, so I have it heavily documented and it only exists in one function. My solution is relative time. I have set the local time to UTC. I am subtracting the GMT offset instead of adding it. I don’t really care about the actual times, all I care about is the difference between two times.  It is working very well.
Good luck

Comment: I'm using PHP and ended up implementing a similar solution.